# Form within React-table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I'm building a budget app and am using react-able to display my transactions. To add a new transaction, I would like to click a `New +` button and then a form render within the react-table at the top with editable fields. On save, the form would POST to my API and the table should re-load with the new transaction at the top. Is this possible or even the best way to go about this?

Transactions.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

import ReactTable from "react-table";
import "react-table/react-table.css";

import TransactionForm from "./TransactionForm";

const API = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/transactions/';

class Transactions extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      transactions: [],
      isLoading: false,
      error: null
    };
  }

  handleAddTransaction() {
    console.log("New button clicked")
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({isLoading: true});

    axios.get(API).then(response => this.setState({transactions: response.data.results, isLoading: false})).catch(error => this.setState({error, isLoading: false}));
  }

  render() {
    const {transactions, isLoading, error} = this.state;

    if (error) {
      return <p>{error.message}</p>;
    }

    if (isLoading) {
      return <p>Loading.............</p>;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        {/* <div><TransactionForm /></div> */}
        <button onClick={() => this.handleAddTransaction()} type="button">New +</button>
        <div>
          <ReactTable
            data = {transactions}
            columns = {[
            {
              Header: 'Date',
              accessor: 'date',
              width: 200
            },
            {
              Header: 'Payee',
              accessor: 'payee',
              width: 400
            },
            {
              Header: 'Category',
              accessor: 'category',
              width: 200
            },
            {
              Header: 'Amount',
              accessor: 'amount',
              width: 200
            },
            {
              Header: 'Balance',
              accessor: 'balance',
              width: 200
            }]}
            defaultPageSize = {500}
            sortable = {false}
            manual
            style={{
              height: "800px"
            }}
            className="-striped -highlight"
          />
        </div>
      </div>)
  };
}

export default Transactions;
```

TransactionForm.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const API = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/transactions/';

class TransactionForm extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      date: "",
      payee: "",
      category: "",
      amount: "",
      is_cleared: true,
      paid_or_deposited: true
    };
  }

  onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  }

  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const {
      date,
      payee,
      category,
      amount,
      is_cleared,
      paid_or_deposited
    } = this.state;

    axios.post(API, {
      date,
      payee,
      category,
      amount,
      is_cleared,
      paid_or_deposited
      })
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result)
      });
  }

  render() {

    const {
      date,
      payee,
      category,
      amount,
      is_cleared,
      paid_or_deposited
    } = this.state;

    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              name="is_cleared"
              value={is_cleared}
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
            <input
              type="text"
              name="date"
              value={date}
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
            <input
              type="text"
              name="payee"
              value={payee}
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
            <input
              type="text"
              name="category"
              value={category}
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
            <input
              type="text"
              name="amount"
              value={amount}
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              name="paid_or_deposited"
              value={paid_or_deposited}
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default TransactionForm;
```

Comment: Create a new component, which will render a form, every time you click on the "New transaction" button, containing all the necessary fields you need to create a new transaction. Create a submit handler inside the `Transactions` component and pass that through props to the form component. Once submitted post the data to the backend and update the transaction list.

Comment: That makes sense conceptually. Any recommendation on how I actually get that form component inside of the table?

Comment: Use props, to pass submit handler function, to take control over the HTTP response inside the Transactions component

Comment: I've added my form component and a click handler for my new button. However, I'm still not understanding how to get the form into the table itself after clicking the new button. Currently the handler just logs when the new button is clicked so I know that works. Could you provide an example based on my code?